# How to install boost on windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I am using Windows 8.1, visual studio community 2013.
I downloaded boost 1.59.
I then open `Developer Command Prompt for VS2013`, run bootstrap.bat, then run b2.exe.

All .lib files are placed under `./stage/lib/`.

I set the c++ include path, and linker path. I built my program successfully and run under debug mode.
Here is the error message I get:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x77394598 in BoostStation.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> > at memory location 0x001BFD74.
```

Here is the break point:

```
throw enable_current_exception(enable_error_info(e)); // from throw_exception.hpp
```

Anyone knows how to solve the problem?
Another question, Are there any .dll files generated by this build and Where can I find them?

Here is my program:
MulticastSender.h

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <string>

class MulticastSender
{
public:
    MulticastSender(const boost::asio::ip::address& multicast_addr, const unsigned short multicast_port)
        : ep_(multicast_addr, multicast_port)
    {
        socket_.reset(new boost::asio::ip::udp::socket(svc_, ep_.protocol()));
    }

    ~MulticastSender()
    {
        socket_.reset(NULL);
    }

public:
    void send_data(const std::string& msg)
    {
        socket_->send_to(boost::asio::buffer(msg), ep_);
    }

private:
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint                  ep_;
    boost::scoped_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket> socket_;
    boost::asio::io_service                         svc_;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MulticastSender.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::ip::address multiCastGroup;
    multiCastGroup.from_string("192.168.32.1");
    MulticastSender outDoor(multiCastGroup, 6000);

    while (true)
    {
        outDoor.send_data("Hello");
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The Boost installation is just fine. The exception means that some system function returned an error. Tell us the exception's message and maybe we can resolve it.

Comment: Where can I find the exception's message? I got a windows pop up with `Unhandled exception at 0x77394598 in BoostStation.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> > at memory location 0x001BFD74.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your boost installation is ok, because obviously you're able to compile and link a program that throws a [`boost::exception`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html).

Catch the exception by wrapping your code in a `try`/`catch` block, then print out the message. I changed your `main`-function accordingly:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MulticastSender.h"
#include "boost/exception.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::ip::address multiCastGroup;
        multiCastGroup.from_string("192.168.32.1");
        MulticastSender outDoor(multiCastGroup, 6000);

        while (true)
        {
            outDoor.send_data("Hello");
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << boost::diagnostic_information(e) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will catch the exception that is thrown by boost and print its message before the program exits.

You should also read up on exceptions in general: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/

Comment: Thank you, I can see the problem is caused by the send_to function. ^^